# Ionic: integrate into iMessage on iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, angularjs, ionic-framework, imessage

everybody. I'm stuck... I'm implementing an iOS chat on ionic framework, and use angular 1.
I have an idea... But in google i can't find any good information about implementing iMessage into my app (or otherwise, it doesn't matter).

For example, like this [service](https://www.circle.com) do

Some ideas i've got from here:

https://github.com/matiastucci/socket-chat-client

Comment: iMessage is a closed platform and does not allow you to include it in your app. You write apps that are included in as add ons in iMessage, but you will need to code them in natively for the most part.

Comment: what's the reason for down vote?

Comment: I did not vote down your question.

Comment: @rckoenes so ionic app can't be added as an add on into iMessage?

Comment: Well you that depends on how far iconic has implement the full SDK. But you need to include and extend a lot a native classes. If these are not exposed correctly then no. Sorry I'm not a guru on ionic since I do all my development natively.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an iMessage app (an app that basically shows in the keyboard area when you are in the iMessage app). But, you can not create an app that will show incoming iMessages or that will send an iMessage to someone.

Information on building an [iMessage app](https://developer.apple.com/imessage/)

Comment: top: iMessage, bottom: my addon